# Hiding shopping details in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to hide shopping details like, add to cart, quantity etc

I know for plugin YITH wordpress catalog mode, but it's not free

CSS is not correct way to hide that elements I think, what do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm from wihch page you exatctlye you want remove shopping related item. Product list page or product details page.

So, to remove add to cart button from product detail page and shop page i.e. product listing page all we need to do is to add these two hooks.

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',

'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',

'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

To remove quantity box from all places

function remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {

return true;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually',

'remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );